# Differences in 2 similar typedef definition

Tags: c++, c, struct, typedef

You can define a Point struct in this way:

```
typedef struct
{
    int x, y;
} Point;
```

and also in this way:

```
typedef struct Point
{
    int x, y;
};
```

What is the difference?

Comment: typedefs words differently in C and in C++, so it is better add a tag in this question.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the `C` code given below,

```
typedef struct
{
    int x, y;
} Point;

int main()
{
  Point a;
  a.x=111;
  a.y=222;
  printf("\n%d %d\n",a.x,a.y);
}
```

The above code will execute without any errors or warnings, whereas the following `C` code will give you an error (`error: 'Point' undeclared`) and a warning (`warning: useless storage class specifier in empty declaration`).

```
typedef struct Point
{
    int x, y;
};

int main()
{
    Point a;
    a.x=111;
    a.y=222;
    printf("\n%d %d\n",a.x,a.y);
}
```

To correct the error you have declare the structure variable `a` as follows,

```
 int main()
 {
    struct Point a;
    a.x=111;
    a.y=222;
    printf("\n%d %d\n",a.x,a.y);
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

The second example, the `typedef` statement have no effect. The compiler will probably ignore it or give you a warning.

What differs from this code:

```
typedef struct Point
{
    int x, y;
} Point;
```

This allow you to use Point as a type, or as a struct. I consider a bad practice to use the struct name as a type, or even as a variable, but you are allowed to do this.

Comment: If you're going to give a `struct` type both a tag name and a `typedef` name, I consider it good practice to use the same identifier for both. Personally, I consider it better practice to omit the `typedef` and refer to the type by its own name, `struct Point`.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: I'm not sure that it's an error, but at least the `typedef` keyword has no effect, since it doesn't provide a name for the typedef. gcc warns about that, both for C and for C++. (BTW, the downvote wasn't mine.)

Comment: It is not a syntax error, but if you try to typedef something, and you typedef nothing, it is wrong. Not saying that in other situations for any obscure reason this would not work or be useful, but for the given example it is wrong.

Comment: @JonatanGoebel: Vote updated. Even better might be to say that the `typedef` keyword has no effect; the statement is not different from the same statement with the `typedef` removed. The whole `typedef` statement still has an effect; it does define a structure tag in C or a type in C++.

Comment: I agree that `typedef struct Point { int x, y; };` is legal, at least in C -- but I consider that to be a minor bug in the language standard. 6.7p2: "A declaration shall declare at least a declarator (other than the parameters of a function or
the members of a structure or union), a tag, or the members of an enumeration.". The above is legal due to a loophole; it happens to declare a tag. The `typedef` keyword is going to be ignored. (gcc warns about this, but it doesn't distinguish between the above and `typedef int;`, which is actually a constraint violation.)

Comment: @EricPostpischil: I certainly don't advocate banning all things with no effect. What clarification does the `typedef` keyword provide in that example?

Comment: @EricPostpischil: Those cases seem contrived, and most of them could be handled with a comment. I don't necessarily advocate changing the language rules now, with the risk of breaking existing code, but I think the legality of `typedef struct foo { int x; };`, which in real-world code is most likely *intended* to be a valid typedef, is an accident of history, not a deliberate feature. 6.7p2 in the C standard just doesn't cover all the cases that (IMHO) it should have.

Comment: When you use the "typedef" keyword you're creating a type? and when you use the "struct" keyword, isn't a type, is only a structure? Correct me if I'm incorrect please.

Comment: @innuendoreplay: A structure declaration with a list of members declares a new type. A typedef declares a synonym for an existing type.